# Rails 3: How to include files from "lib" directory when running tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

When I run:

```
ruby -I test test/unit/job_test.rb
```

from the application root directory, I got the following error:

```
.../app/models/name_position.rb:9:in `<class:NamePosition>': 
     uninitialized constant NamePosition::PositionManager (NameError)
from .../app/models/name_position.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from .../app/models/ac_buyer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
...
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
# app/models/ac_buyer.rb
class AcBuyer < NamePosition  
end 

# app/models/name_position.rb
class NamePosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include PositionManager
end

# lib/position_manager.rb
module PositionManager
  ...
end
```

It looks like when running tests, the files from the `lib` directory are not loaded automatically.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting this in your application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```